# MPAndroidChart BarChart xValues Issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I noticed an issue with the `BarChart` of `MPAndroidChart` and need a fix. First my code:

```
this.barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.bar_fragment_bar_chart);
this.barChart.setDrawYValues(true);
this.barChart.setDrawXLabels(false);
this.barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
this.barChart.setDrawBorder(false);
this.barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
this.barChart.setDrawHorizontalGrid(true);
this.barChart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false);
this.barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
this.barChart.setDescription("");
this.barChart.setNoDataTextDescription("");
this.barChart.set3DEnabled(false);
```

My `xValues` are simple dates:

```
ArrayList<String> xValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
    String StringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime();
    Long value = Long.parseLong(StringValue) * 1000;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(value));

    xValues.add(date);
}
```

Now i have multiple datasets:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesMonday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesTuesday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesWednesday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesThursday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesFriday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesSaturday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValuesSunday = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
    String stringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getValue();
    int dayOfWeek = Helper.getDayOfWeek(measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime());
    float value = Float.parseFloat(stringValue);

    switch(dayOfWeek) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        yValuesMonday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        yValuesTuesday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        yValuesWednesday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        yValuesThursday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        yValuesFriday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        yValuesSaturday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        yValuesSunday.add(new BarEntry(value, i));
        break;
    }
}

BarDataSet barDataSetMonday = new BarDataSet(yValuesMonday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_monday));

barDataSetMonday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetTuesday = new BarDataSet(yValuesTuesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_tuesday));

barDataSetTuesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetWednesday = new BarDataSet(yValuesWednesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_wednesday));

barDataSetWednesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetThursday = new BarDataSet(yValuesThursday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_thursday));

barDataSetThursday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetFriday = new BarDataSet(yValuesFriday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_friday));

barDataSetFriday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetSaturday = new BarDataSet(yValuesSaturday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_saturday));

barDataSetSaturday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));

BarDataSet barDataSetSunday = new BarDataSet(yValuesSunday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_sunday));

barDataSetSunday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));

ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();

dataSets.add(barDataSetMonday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetTuesday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetWednesday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetThursday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetFriday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetSaturday);
dataSets.add(barDataSetSunday);

BarData data = new BarData(xValues, dataSets);

this.barChart.setData(data);
this.barChart.animateY(1000);
```

My Problem now is that the `xLabels` and the `xValues` arent matching at all:

[image]

The bars are placed far far behind the `xLabels` and there is extremely much space between the last entry and the entry before the last entry.

I also tested how it looks when I put all data into one data-set. the `xLabels` also aren't matching the `xValues`:

[image]

How can I fix that issue?

**EDIT**

[image]

The date you see here in the `xLabels` belongs to the bar. So why is the position of the `xLabel` so far away from the bar?

**EDIT 2:**

With `LineChart`:

```
protected void initData() {
    List<MeasureDataListEntry> measureDataListEntry = null;

    if(this.favourite) {
        measureDataListEntry = this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite.getMeasureDataList().getMeasureDataListEntries();
    } else {
        measureDataListEntry = this.sessionMeasureDataList.getMeasureDataList().getMeasureDataListEntries();
    }

    ArrayList<String> xValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesMonday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesTuesday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesWednesday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesThursday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesFriday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesSaturday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yValuesSunday = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
        String StringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime();
        Long value = Long.parseLong(StringValue) * 1000;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(value));

        xValues.add(date);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
        String stringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getValue();
        int dayOfWeek = Helper.getDayOfWeek(measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime());
        float value = Float.parseFloat(stringValue);

        switch(dayOfWeek) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            yValuesMonday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            yValuesTuesday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            yValuesWednesday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            yValuesThursday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            yValuesFriday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            yValuesSaturday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            yValuesSunday.add(new Entry(value, i));
            break;
        }
    }

    LineDataSet lineDataSetMonday = new LineDataSet(yValuesMonday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_monday));

    lineDataSetMonday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));
    lineDataSetMonday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));
    lineDataSetMonday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetMonday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetMonday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetMonday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetTuesday = new LineDataSet(yValuesTuesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_tuesday));

    lineDataSetTuesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));
    lineDataSetTuesday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));
    lineDataSetTuesday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetTuesday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetTuesday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetTuesday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetWednesday = new LineDataSet(yValuesWednesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_wednesday));

    lineDataSetWednesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));
    lineDataSetWednesday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));
    lineDataSetWednesday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetWednesday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetWednesday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetWednesday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetThursday = new LineDataSet(yValuesThursday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_thursday));

    lineDataSetThursday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));
    lineDataSetThursday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));
    lineDataSetThursday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetThursday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetThursday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetThursday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetFriday = new LineDataSet(yValuesFriday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_friday));

    lineDataSetFriday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));
    lineDataSetFriday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));
    lineDataSetFriday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetFriday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetFriday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetFriday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetSaturday = new LineDataSet(yValuesSaturday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_saturday));

    lineDataSetSaturday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));
    lineDataSetSaturday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));
    lineDataSetSaturday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetSaturday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetSaturday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetSaturday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));

    LineDataSet lineDataSetSunday = new LineDataSet(yValuesSunday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_sunday));

    lineDataSetSunday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));
    lineDataSetSunday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));
    lineDataSetSunday.setLineWidth(1f);
    lineDataSetSunday.setCircleSize(4f);
    lineDataSetSunday.setFillAlpha(65);
    lineDataSetSunday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));

    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();

    dataSets.add(lineDataSetMonday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetTuesday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetWednesday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetThursday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetFriday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetSaturday);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSetSunday);

    LineData data = new LineData(xValues, dataSets);

    this.lineChart.setData(data);
    this.lineChart.animateX(1000);
}
```

Everything is working fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want.
But **to center the x-labels** above the bars, call:

```
chart.getXLabels().setCenterXLabelText(true);
```

As for the groups inside the barchart, maybe you should check out the example project and see what is done here:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java

**Update**:

If you simply want to have a separate color for each day, put all entries in one DataSet, and add 7 colors (one for each day) to the dataset.
The x-values array in that case needs to be as long as the array of entries you provided, containing the different dates.

Comment: The example you showed is NOT what i want to do. I have different datasets, one dataset for each day of the week. I dont want to group them or anything. They should just be plotted as they are. I just wanted all values of monday to have equal color. same for tuesday and so on.

Comment: I added another picture to my post to show the problem... the date you can see there belongs to the bar... i guess you can see the strange positioning of the xLabel.

Comment: Oh i found out something more: the bars arent placed in the correct order. For example, the first value i added is the value 145 which belongs to the dataset of tuesday at the 23.11.2014. but the first value in the diagram is 238 which belongs to the dataset of monday on 24.11.2014. So the bar chart is somehow mixing the values. So i guess the datasets are having an issue. they are ignoring the index parameter of `new BarEntry(value, i)`

Comment: How should your updated answer solve the problem? How can the dataset automatically know which day is monday and which not? the values arent ordered.

Comment: i added another piece of code and a picture for my linechart. here everything is working fine. its exactly the same way i initalize my datasets.

Comment: Now i know what you mean. The situation you described cannot be created with a barchart, since the bars would overlap if they are at the same x-index. This is why barcharts instead are grouped if multiple datasets are used. Letting bars overlap is not possible.

Comment: yeah... but they wouldnt overlap because they never have the same index. thats not possible from my code.

Comment: Yeah, that is not possible in your scenario. In many other scenarios (that other users of this library might create), it is. This library was not created and made public to fit the specific requirements of a single individual, but the broad mass.

Comment: I understand that. I will make a fork to fix that, it is possible to implement a configuration to make it working for all scenarios.