# Related to: MPAndroidChart BarChart xValues Issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

English isn't my first language. So, Please excuse me if I'm not so clear, feel free to ask details.

I'm having the same problem as in this post: [MPAndroidChart BarChart xValues Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645883/mpandroidchart-barchart-xvalues-issue)

In a barchart with 2 series xVals labels aren't displayed correctly, here are some test cases:

**case 1**

```
xVals = from 1 (index 0) to 30 (index 29) (days in a month, say april)
set1 = 3 values for 3 days (10,17,22): a.e. barentry(100,10), barentry(200,17), barentry(300,22)  
set2 = 3 values for 3 days (4,11,18): a.e. barentry(100,4), barentry(200,11), barentry(300,18)
```

in this case the `barchart` displays bars and xvals labels as independent, any bar is below his xvals label

**case 2**

```
xVals = from 1 (index 0) to 30 (index 29) (days in april)  
set1 = as previous but added 0 values with set2 index : a.e. barentry(0,4), barentry(100,10), barentry(0,11),barentry(200,17), barentry(0,18), barentry(300,22)  
set2 = as previous but added 0 values with set1 index : a.e. barentry(100,4), barentry(0,10), barentry(200,11),barentry(0,17), barentry(300,18), barentry(0,22)
```

in this case the `barchart` displays bars and xvals labels as independent, any bar is below his xvals label

**case 3**

```
xVals = from 1 (index 0) to 30 (index 29) (days in april)  
set1 filled with 0 for everyday barentry(0,[0 to 29]), then added values for 3 days (10,17,22): barentry(0,10)....  
set2 filled with 0 for everyday barentry(0,[0 to 29]), then added values for 3 days (4,11,18): barentry(0,4)....
```

in this case I can see every bar in the right place with relative xvals label but it's horrible to see all these 0s!

Please take note that if in case 1 I don't add set2 (so a simple barchart with 1 series) everything it's ok without the need 0 values.

The question is: How can I get rid of the 0 values where not needed (as in example in days 1 to 3 and so on)?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
PFA screenshots, both are the same graph the only difference are sets with/without all days value.
The code is same from multidataset example and it works fine for every graph.

Only days with data: http://mysite.altervista.org/temp/some.png

All days: http://mysite.altervista.org/temp/all.png

Answer (score 0):

For getting rid of the zeroes, use the [ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface), and return an empty string whenever the value is zero.

Concerning the issue with the x-labels: I'm not sure what the issue is here.

The chart does only dispalys as many x-values as there is space on the screen. The position of the x-labels depends on their position in the xvalues-array, and is independent from the position of your entries.

If you zoom in, all x-values should appear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll take a look to ValueFormatter.
I tried zooming and yes all values appear but they're not in the corresponding value of the bar.
I'm recording swim training sessions, so if i'm rappresenting haw many sessions in a year (or comparing years on the same graph, each set is one year) all goes fine, every year has 12 months.  
Displaying month data works fine if i have only 1 month, when i'm comparing the same month in different years all is messed up if i'm omitting days without sessions.
I'll revert back the code to post some screenshot (if i found some time tomorrow!).